# How to delete lines from first match to the end?

Tags: sed

I can use this command to keep the lines down to the first match of a pattern ('\r' line in this case).

```
sed -e '1,/^\r$/!d'
```

How to delete lines from the first match to the end? Thanks.

Comment: Please try: `sed '/^\r$/,$d'`

Comment: If the first match occurs within a line, should the entire line be deleted, or just the part of the line the match an after?  Example, say the target string is "b", and the input is the single line "abc".  Please clarify if the desired output would be "a", or "" (nothing at all).